# How to include a module with browserify but not process it's requires

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I'm attempting to create a common build of my project; in doing such I have a module that provides some boiler functions dependent on environment:

```js
if (/* running in browser */) {
    module.exports.WebSocket = WebSocket
    // ...
} else {
    module.exports.WebSocket = require('ws');
    // ...
}
```

How do I get browserfy to include this file but not process or include the `require()`s with in.

I've tried the following but its still including the ws dep in the final output:

```
browserify --noparse=$PWD/boilers.js index.js > bundle.js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I just needed to keep dependency node modules from being bundled, to do so I used:

```
browserify --no-bundle-external index.js > bundle.js
```